# JdataView and Jbinary, how to read video metadata?

Tags: javascript, video, metadata

I need to read metadata (like title,author,ecc...) from a video uploaded by an html form. I need to use js. I'm trying to use JDataView and Jbinary :

```
          jBinary.loadData(selectedFile).then(function (data) {

                console.log(data);

                // here you get data from <input type="file" /> that you can use in jDataView/jBinary constructors

                var b2 = new jBinary(new jDataView(data, 5, 10, true), {
                  MetaName: ['string', 30]
                });

                console.log(b2);

              });
```

With this code i can't see any meta in logs object , what's wrong?